# how to set a priority high accuracy location for the following code

Tags: java, android, android-location, android-gps

someone  already did this code in the project. But how to set a priority high accuracy in the location manager. They use location manager to get the current location.

So any one can help out. This not working if any possibilities to change the logic .

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;


// flag for GPS status
public boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
       private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; 
                      // 10 meters to 1 meters change by me ..

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; 
                   // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public  Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null ) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}



/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
}


public double getLatitude()
{
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */

public double getLongitude()
{
    if(location != null)
    {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: It's bad code. Just forget it, read some Android documentation and write proper code instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

You shoul add criteria:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // Choose your accuracy requirement.

locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true)
```

Comment: try to update the Accuracy high . but when i run the app it  causes crashing